# Как рассчитать высоту TextView по заданному размеру его текста?

Tags: android, textview, android-textview

Зная заданный размер`TextView` в `sp`через

> android:textSize="XXsp"

можно ли рассчитать какая высота будет у него в `px`на тестируемом устройстве заранее? 
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, паддингов нет, android:includeFontPadding="false"

**UPD**
Протестировал на нескольких эмуляторах и телефоне, похоже что формула выглядит следующим образом:

```
height = ОКРУГЛВВЕРХ(textSize * scaledDensity * (7/6))
```

Не знаю только, на всех ли устройствах будет она работать.

Answer (score 1):

если после того, как текст будет добавлен в `TextView`, можно узнать вот таким способом

```
int totalLineCount = textView.getLineCount();
int lineHeight = textView.getLineHeight();
int totlaHeight = totalLineCount * lineHeight;
```

Comment: Хороший способ. Но все равно не понятно как рассчитывается getLineHeight(). Например для textSize = 30sp, height = 71px на моем девайсе, при плотности 2.

Comment: там еще паддинг шрифта берется и еще парочка вещей :)

Comment: а можно поподробнее? Я пытался смотреть в исходниках, но в них ничего не понять.

Answer (score 0):

```
float scaledDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
int px = scaledDensity*sp;
```

Comment: Это получится размер шрифта в px, но не высота TextView. Высота получается больше.

Comment: @iamtihonov Так это зависит не только от textSize, но еще от layout_height, падингов и марджинов. Если знаешь их значения - то просто прибавь к этому.

Comment: android:layout_height="wrap_content", падингов и маржинов нет. Я тоже думал что тогда должно быть одно и тоже значение, но протестировав оказалось что TextView выше

Comment: @iamtihonov Еще зависит от бекграунда. Он может быть подключен в стилях. Как стандартных, так и пользовательских. А не проще получить значение через getHeight()?

Comment: Так я и делаю, да возможно стандартный бекграунд добавляет высоты  TextView или такая реализация у него. Интересно, можно ли её заранее узнать.

Comment: @iamtihonov У textView есть `fontPadding`. Его можно убрать `android:includeFontPadding="false"`. А как узнать его значение я не нашел. Видимо оно зависит от `textSize`.

Comment: Да действительно если указать android:includeFontPadding="false", высота TextView становится меньше, но все равно не равна значению  scaledDensity*sp.

Answer (score 0):

Есть вот такой вариант, пробовали?

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = textView.getViewTreeObserver(); 
    viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onGlobalLayout() { 
            int width = textView.getWidth();
            int height= textView.getHeight()
            textView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        } 
    });
```

Comment: зачем обращаться к этому слушателю, любой виджет и так вернет свои размеры через геттеры.

Comment: getHeight() я вызывал при тестировании по клику view, в этом методе нет необходимости.

Answer (score 0):

Таким образом можно получить размеры текста, написанного нужным вам размером шрифта:

```
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG);

paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setColor(color);
paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
paint.setTextSize(textSize); //размер шрифта в **пикселях**

Rect bounds = new Rect();
String text = "your text here";
paint.getTextBounds(text , 0, text.length(), bounds);

int height =  bounds.height();//высота
int width =  bounds.width();//ширина
```

Comment: Нужно расчитать, какой будет высота виджета `TextView`, зная размер текста в *sp* до того, как этот текст будет выведен.

Answer (score 0):

Напрямую не подойдет?

```
textView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
int height = textView.getMeasuredHeight();
int width = textView.getMeasuredWidth();
```

Comment: Это значение мы получаем по факту, как раз его нужно рассчитать заранее, до отображения.

Comment: тогда, как-то так: int measuredHeight = (new StaticLayout(measuredText, paint, targetWidth, Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f, true)).getHeight();